# Detect flying players in skyblock

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I'm creating a vanilla 1.10 skyblock server and I'm trying to find a way to detect flying players. I considered using a /tesfor command to check for air 1 block below the player, but if a player is crouched and hanging off of a block to extend their island (making a "bridge" out of cobblestone, for example) that would give a false positive. There's also the possibility that a player will be using an elytra, or falling off their island into the void. Is there a feasible work around for this?

Comment: Tricky.. you probably want to test for client cheats? Have you tried the `Motion` tag? I saw someone using it for exactly this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

As Rudolf L. Jelínek said, you could make command blocks try and detect cheating players, but I would strongly recommend not doing that, and instead using an anticheat plugin. When I had a server, we had a huge cheating problem, so we had to install tons and tons of anticheat plugins. I would personally recommend [NCP / NoCheatPlus](https://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/nocheatplus/), just because of its config file (which you can make ONLY have fly detection, and you can choose what happens) it is, in my honest opinion, one of the best free Bukkit anticheat plugins out there. If you are looking for a paid alternative, there is a plugin called KnightFall. I couldn't find the link with a simple Google Search, but it is the top-of-the-line anticheat.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use more commands to test for a flying player. What I used is to combine these two commands, and when **both** return true, execute the command you want:

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ testforblock air ~ ~-1 ~

/testfor @a {Motion:[0.0,0.0,0.0]}
```

And when both are true, execute the command you want, eg.

```
/say @a Warning: Flying player
```

This command will be executed if a player is on the air **and** doesn't move.

Comment: Does it test positive if they're hanging off of a block when crouching?

Comment: @theBeaks Didnt test this; I will check this when I return home.